# Most efficient way of checking list membership of more that one value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Take the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
if 1 in a or 2 in a:
     print 'found'
```

Is there a cleaner/more elegant way of doing this? Perhaps:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
if set(a) & set(b):
    print found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]

print any(x in a for x in b)
True
```

Comment: This seems the most elegant and the fastest way

Answer (score 4):

Your second example based on `set` doesn't work because it will always return `True` for non-empty `a`/`b`. However sets are likely the right to use:

```
if set(b).issubset(set(a)):
    print "found"
```

Please note that `b = set([])` is always a subset of `set(a)`.

Update: I just noticed that you only want to know if any of the items in `b` is part of `a` which is different from my proposed solution. In that case I think a simple if/elif/else is the best solution. You could try to use a dict or another iterable with fast contains-lookup.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean -- bool(set([5, 6]) & set([1,2,3,4]))  This definitely is not True.  Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Don't fully understand your first sentence. Wouldn't the '&' be evaluated first and then offered up to the 'if' for evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too simple, but `if...elif` seems fine to me:

```
found = False

if 1 in a:
     found = True
elif 2 in a:
     found = True
```

This only checks if `2` is in the list if `1` isn't, since you're only looking to see if either is in the list (not caring which one), this should be good

**Pros:**

- Its simple
- You can save a check on `2` if `1` is already in the list
- No need to convert `a` to a different type (which aides efficiency)

**Cons:**

- This won't get you any points for flair

---

**Timing Comparison:**

```
basecase = """
a = [1,2,3,4]
if 1 in a or 2 in a:
    print 'found'
"""

case1 = """
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
if set(b).issubset(set(a)):
    print 'found'
"""

case2 = """
found = False
if 1 in a:
     found = True
elif 2 in a:
     found = True
"""

case3 = """
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,2]
print any(x in a for x in b)
"""
```

Using `print min(timeit.Timer(<case>).repeat(8, 1000))` yields

```
basecase = 0.0953138421204
case1 = 0.0974782045301
case2 = 0.0958207179797
case3 = 0.068283250742
```

Comment: This solution does seem pretty horrible to me. Why would we go with a temporary variable and spread out the `or` clause to an elif clause?

Comment: @ch3ka, any particular reason why?

Comment: `if 1 in a or b in a` is shorter and more precise than `if 1 in a ... elif b in a` - and the first one already short-circuits, so your pro's don't hold.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if set(a) <= set(b):
    print found
```

But I can't tell if it's more efficient than your code.